# How to merge PR on forked project on Bitbucket with mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

I have forked a mercurial project on bitbucet.org and I would like to merge a PR (to the original project) to an "old-version" branch in my fork. Is that possible?  I haven't found any direct way of doing it and I don't see an option to download the PR as a patch file.

Comment: What about pulling from that repository and do the merge in your local repository to whatever version you like

Comment: How would I go about pulling down the PR from bitbucket?

Comment: Do just what the name "pull request" means: pull from that repo to your local one - like you would pull from any other repo. And then work locally.

Comment: @planetmaker I'm feeling a little dense here, but I don't know how pull the PR (at least not when I don't own the repo).  How would I go about pulling https://bitbucket.org/mchaput/whoosh/pull-requests/78/functionweighting-class-max_quality-not/diff into the 2.4x branch of my forked repo: https://bitbucket.org/datakortet/whoosh/branch/2.4x (the pull requests menu is empty in my fork..)

Comment: Don't use the webinterface at all. Use mercurial itself. On your local machine, laptop or desktop.

Comment: @planetmaker ok, that's fine.. How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just ignore any webinterface you are offered and use the VCS you use, how it was designed: pull and merge the remote changes in the completely traditional way with mercurial's own devices:

1. in your local repo, pull from the repository which contains the interesting pull request. Pull the revision you are interested in:

   `hg pull -rXXXX https://url.to.repo`

   where XXXX is the tip of the interesting changesets, the HASH as mentioned in the pull request
2. in your local repo, update to the revision YYYY you want to see the just pulled changesets merged **into**

   `hg update -rYYYY`
3. Merge the changeset to the currently checked-out revision:

   `hg merge -rXXXX`

   where XXXX is the very same changesetID as you pulled before from the remote repo. Of course you might need to solve any merge conflicts, if the base of your desired merge point differs from the base the pull request is based on.